# tar operation taking extremely long time

Tags: linux, iscsi, tar

Wonder if anyone can help with this issue, we running RHL 5 on HP Proliant DL580 G7 it has 2xCPU @1.87GHz 6XCORES each & 64GB RAM. lately backing up a directory (62GB) with tar 
(tar -czvf filename.tgz /directory/to/backup) is taking up to 3 hours.

The directory being backed up is a LUN connect via iscsi at 1Gb/s NIC. So far i have tested the R/W to that LUN and i am getting 35MB/s to 40MB/s. viewing top tar is hitting 100% processor usage.

although i have my money on processor performance, i would like to hear some of your opnion on this. i need to uderstand why its taking 3-4 hours to complete the tar process.

any ideas?

thanks & regards.

Comment: As you mention top, is there any I/O wait?

Comment: the closest thing to "wait" i have seen is this "scsi_wq_2" process poping up, still trying to understand what it means. anyone?

Comment: Tar is rarely a CPU-bound operation. I agree with @tink...check your iowait.

Comment: Check the value of `%wa` in the header of `top`.

Comment: @EEAA -- examine the tar command line CAREFULLY, it has a 'z' option in it.  (Hint: being compressed, not just copied.)

Comment: It's time for a smarter backup solution.

Comment: @mdpc - good catch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're compressing (gzip, even) 62 GB of data. At 40 MB/s, that transfer would take ~30 minutes on its own. However, gzip involves the CPU greatly. If you're pinning both cores at 100%, then there's your answer.

Comment: This is the answer. Remove the compression and it'll speed right up.

Comment: at the cost of increased destination size.

Comment: Well yes, it'd be the same size as the source (62 GB).

Comment: gzip was single threaded last I checked.

Comment: @EEAA, just checked the value of %wa during tar opetration and it briefly reached 80+ but did not stay there for long.

Comment: Hi All, i ended up using lbzip2, and gladly its now taking 30 minutes to backup the data. i will accept NATHAN C suggestion as an answer.